# How to get the third column of text file in C programming

Tags: c

I have a text file that contains:

```
1   1   1
1   2   2
1   3   2
1   7   5
1   8   4
1   9   4
1   10  2
...
```

and this is my function:

```
void addRatings()
{
    int n,m,l;
    int a[50][100];
    MovieR = fopen("d://ratings.txt","r");
    l = LineNum(MovieR);
    MovieR = fopen("d://ratings.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        fscanf(MovieR,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\n",&n,&m,&a[n][m]);
    }   
}
```

Now I want to get the first and second column for n and m
then I want to give third column to the a[n][m].
How can I do that?

Comment: I would not trust that `n` and `m`already have the correct values when using them to access `a[n][m]`...

Comment: It seems very odd that you are opening the file twice, and you appear to be doing that for the purpose of first determining the total number of lines in the file.  That is an anti-pattern.  Just open the file and read until there is no more data.  IOW, instead of looping from 0 to l, just do `while( fscanf(...) == ...)`. Using this idiom helps to reinforce the absolutely necessary practice of ALWAYS checking the value returned by scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the third value into a temporary variable, and then store that value into the array if and only if the following conditions are met:

- `fscanf` returned 3, meaning that it actually found three numbers
- the value for `n` is between 0 and 49 inclusive
- the value for `m` is between 0 and 99 inclusive

And the code doesn't need to count the number of lines (using `LineNum()`). The loop should end when `fscanf` runs out of numbers to read, i.e. returns something other than 3.

The resulting code looks something like this:

```
void addRatings(void)
{
    int a[50][100] = {{0}};                             // initialize all ratings to 0
    FILE *MovieR = fopen("d://ratings.txt", "r");
    if (MovieR != NULL)
    {
        int n, m, rating;
        while (fscanf(MovieR, "%d%d%d", &n, &m, &rating) == 3)  // loop until end-of-file
        {
            if (n < 0 || n > 49 || m < 0 || m > 99)             // check for valid indexes
                break;
            a[n][m] = rating;
        }
        fclose(MovieR);
    }
}
```